# Discord.py with Atom: error author is required argument that is missing, message is not defined

Tags: python, discord.py

The block of code throwing the codes.

```py
import discord
import os
import random
import sys
import RS9_List
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get

intents = discord.Intents().all()
intents.members=True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix= '.', intents=intents)
fetch_offline_members = True

@client.command(aliases=['in9', 'In9', 'I9', 'i 9'])
async def i9(ctx):
    if ctx.author==client.user:
        return
    await ctx.author.send('{ctx.author.display_name} Has Joined a Red Star 9 Que')
```

I have been stuck on this block of code for 3 days now. I wish to have the command .i9 reply by mentioning the author. This is the first step this code will do, and i cannot seem to get it to work.

issues i have had are, defining the author, defining the member, and above. I am new to coding, spent several days reading the documents. doing practice codes, other exercises. I am still having trouble.

any help, resource, solve, insight, ect I am happy to accept with open ears.

I appreciate your time and commitment to this matter deeply.

```
Ignoring exception in command i9:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Mike\Desktop\Discordbot\Seymourlist.py", line 36, in i9
    await ctx.author.send('Joined Red Star 9-->{}'.format(message.author.name))
NameError: name 'message' is not defined

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 859, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'message' is not defined
```

Comment: Can you add the whole traceback? The code that you provided shouldn't throw the error you mentioned in the title

Comment: Please edit your question and add it there, not in the comments

Answer (score 0):

`if ctx.author == client.user` doesn't make sense, you can try:

```py
async def i9(ctx):
    await ctx.author.send(f'{ctx.author.display_name} Has Joined a Red Star 9 Que')
```